# reprex showing correct output but rstudio console is showing error

Tags: r, reprex

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.3
mtcars = as_tibble(mtcars)
cars_nested = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest()

cars_fitted = cars_nested %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, function(x) lm(mpg ~ disp, data = x)))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

When I ran this code in Rstudio, I am getting the following errors. Any help?

````
> mtcars = as_tibble(mtcars)
> cars_nested = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest()
> cars_fitted = cars_nested %>% 
+   mutate(fit = map(data, function(x) lm(mpg ~ disp, data = x)))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `fit`.
x object 'disp' not found
i Input `fit` is `map(data, function(x) lm(mpg ~ disp, data = x))`.
i The error occured in group 1: cyl = 4.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. ```
````

Comment: What if you change `map` to `purrr::map` ?

Comment: This means that you ran something in the console that altered your environment or the mtcars dataset, which you did not keep in your script file. If you restart R and run your code again, are you still getting the error?

Comment: Still same error.

Comment: Weird. The code does not generate an error on my end, so there must be something else you're doing that's leading to the error.

Comment: @Phil I found the error. Thanks for the restarting Rstudio suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.  I found why I am getting these errors.  In the earlier code, I unknowingly nested the mtcars to the same mtcars dataset. So there are only cyl and data columns.  Thats why I got the  error.